# Sudden errors from Firebase verifyIdToken

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Has anyone ever experienced sudden timeout errors from `verifyIdToken()` of the Firebase Admin SDK (Node.js)?

Hi,  We started getting sudden timeouts when calling `verifyIdToken()` of the Firebase Admin SDK (Node.js) from a Firebase function.

```
code: 'auth/argument-error',     message: 'Error while making request: connect ETIMEDOUT.
```

A new deployment seems to have fixed it though.

But why does it happen in the first place?